# Success stories of Eclipse as an application framework (RCP)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I keep reading about [Eclipse as an application framework](http://electronicdesign.com/Articles/ArticleID/11885/11885.html) (i.e. about [Eclipse Rich Client Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/home/categories/rcp.php)). I am unable to find comprehensive list of success stories of Eclipse as an application framework (RCP) other than Eclipse as an IDE which is extremely popular. I have seen [customer testimonials of Netbeans platform](http://platform.netbeans.org/articles/diff-nb-eclipse.html), but not for Eclipse Rich Client platform.

What are the case-studies or success stories of Eclipse as an application framework (Rich Client Platform) in commercial and open source world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a list of open source products built on the Eclipse Rich Client Platform:
http://www.eclipse.org/community/rcpos.php

Commercial products:
http://www.eclipse.org/community/rcpcp.php

Comment: There is also a list of case studies here: 
http://www.eclipse.org/community/rcp.php

Comment: The first page you mentioned is deprecated. Is there a non-deprecated version of this site?

Answer (score 7):

I can add my own humble [success story](http://www.moonlit-software.com) using RCP as a client platform. In has a slow learning curve, but once mastered, there are huge benefits. In particular :

- Platform neutral. It runs well on windows and linuxes, there are little surprises here and there, but overall it's being great so far.
- Built in update management, fantastic for version releases and fixes.
- It scales up great, adding new features is almost painless.
- Being a platform and not just a GUI library, it gives lots of perks.

Cons :

- Not every application fits the eclipse philosophy and view/editor paradigm.
- It's relatively tough for beginners
- It can be way too cumbersome for achieving simple tasks
- Documentation is not the best, community is rather small, comparing to other alternatives..

Overall, I don't regret by choosing it. I personally hate web based clumsy and slow performing interfaces. Here you've got native, fast and responsive GUI naturally integrated with the desktop.

Comment: +1 for the "Not every application fits the eclipse philosophy and view/editor paradigm."

Answer (score 2):

My company was quite sucessful creating an aircraft mission planning system using the Eclipse RCP framework. It was not without it's hassles ( mostly the fact that the new interfaces you are supposed to use are not well documented much of the time ), but it did give us a huge leg up and provided a lot of useful archetecture.

In many respects we are just an editor, but instead of a text file you are modifying a database describing a mission with an aircraft, and many of the interactions are through a 3D globe displayed in a view. Databinding helps keep the various views and editors in sync all the time ( although the threading issues between the SWT application and a third-party AWT widget through data-binding calls was a nightmare I'd rather not revisit )

It was a complex program that basically took three developers who didn't know Eclipse going in about a year to write. Today we are extending it for other customers by adding more plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [XMind](http://www.xmind.net/). It's a mind mapping application on top of RCP. I know some seasoned users who didn't realize it was a Java application at all. It just looks good.

Comment: That part about "didn't realize it was java" is the most thrilling idea there!